# Merge(Combine) several .xlsx with one worksheet into just one workbook (Python)

Tags: python, excel

I've been trying to do this and I really got no clue. I've search a lot and i know that i can merge the files with easily with VBA or other languages, but i really want to do it with Python.

Can anyone get me on track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wished there was a straight forward support from openpyxl/xlsxwriter to copy sheets across different workbooks.

However, I see you would have to mash up a recipe using a couple of libraries:

1. One for reading the worksheet data and,
2. Another for writing data to a unified xlsx

For both of the above there are lot of options in terms of python packages.

Comment: Could you provide some hints about the "lot of options"?

Comment: For reading sheets data, xlrd can be used. pandas can be used as well, however, it might be an overkill. For writing sheets, openpyxl and xlsxwriter would do the trick!